# Reference request of softmax function

Tags: references, softmax, history

What paper should I cite to reference softmax?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function#History),

> The softmax function was used in statistical mechanics as the Boltzmann distribution in the foundational paper Boltzmann (1868),[8] formalized and popularized in the influential textbook Gibbs (1902).[9]

> The use of the softmax in decision theory is credited to Luce (1959),[10]:1 who used the axiom of independence of irrelevant alternatives in rational choice theory to deduce the softmax in Luce's choice axiom for relative preferences.

> In machine learning, the term "softmax" is credited to John S. Bridle in two 1989 conference papers, Bridle (1990a):[10]:1 and Bridle (1990b):[3]

Depending on your area of application, one or more of these sources should fit the goal.

**References**

- [8] Boltzmann, Ludwig (1868). "Studien über das Gleichgewicht der lebendigen Kraft zwischen bewegten materiellen Punkten" [Studies on the balance of living force between moving material points]. *Wiener Berichte*. 58: 517–560.
- Bridle, John S. (1990a). Soulié F.F.; Hérault J. (eds.). *Probabilistic Interpretation of Feedforward Classification Network Outputs, with Relationships to Statistical Pattern Recognition*. Neurocomputing: Algorithms, Architectures and Applications (1989). NATO ASI Series (Series F: Computer and Systems Sciences). 68. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer. pp. 227–236. doi:10.1007/978-3-642-76153-9_28.
- Bridle, John S. (1990a). Soulié F.F.; Hérault J. (eds.). *Probabilistic Interpretation of Feedforward Classification Network Outputs, with Relationships to Statistical Pattern Recognition*. Neurocomputing: Algorithms, Architectures and Applications (1989). NATO ASI Series (Series F: Computer and Systems Sciences). 68. Berlin, Heidelberg: Springer. pp. 227–236. doi:10.1007/978-3-642-76153-9_28.
- [10] Gao, Bolin; Pavel, Lacra (2017). "On the Properties of the Softmax Function with Application in Game Theory and Reinforcement Learning". arXiv:1704.00805 [math.OC].
- [9] Gibbs, Josiah Willard (1902). *Elementary Principles in Statistical Mechanics*.
- [3] Sako, Yusaku (2018-06-02). "Is the term "softmax" driving you nuts?". Medium.

Comment: The use of a function of the form $x\to 1/(1+\exp(-x))$ surely dates back almost 200 years before Boltzmann, back to when (in the late 17th century) people started formulating and solving ordinary differential equations.